# Is it okay to say: I can't tell you it because it is a secret

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say:

> "I can't tell you **it** because **it** is a secret".

This sounds better:

> "I can't tell you **that** because **that** is a secret".

But if I break the first sentence, it is okay to say, "because it is a secret". As I am using "it" in this second phrase I believe I should use "it" in the first phrase also. But "I can't tell you it" doesn't sound right to me.

Thanks!!

Comment: Your claim ***This sounds better*** is simply ***mistaken***. Unnecessary repetition of a reference to the object (using ***it, that, what you want to know,*** or any other alternative) contributes nothing to fluency or "naturalness" in this context - it just sounds pointlessly verbose. Avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to shorten it, you can say, "I can't tell you; it's a secret!" Because "it" refers back to the secret.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, try this: *I can't tell you **that** because **it**'s a secret.*

The second '**it**' refers back to the first '**that**'.

If you want to use **it**, you should say: *I can't tell you **about** it, ...*